# When doing a git merge my newly added files are deleted, why?

Tags: git, merge

I've branched from *master* to *feature* and in *feature* i've added the file `CMakeLists.txt` (git add). Some more commits and merges have happened in between both on *master* and *feature*. Now that I merge *master* into *feature* I find that `CMakeLists.txt` is deleted during the merge (using `git status`). My question is: why and how did this happen?

I tried to check for changes on `CMakeLists.txt` on the master branch by using:

`git log master -- CMakeLists.txt`

This does not return anything and thus leads me to conclude that `CMakeLists` does not exist on *master*. Is this the correct command to use? How can I figure out what went wrong?

Comment: `git status` shows uncommitted changes, while merge is for commited. It's a little difficult to understand what exactly you are doing from the description. Probably if you could create a new repo and reproduce the issue and show all the commands you do.

Comment: If `CMakeLists.txt` doesn't show on Git logs, then it looks like you didn't commit it.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this problem as described. I have not been able to figure out what's different between what I explain is happening and what is actually happening. Is there some way to find out what has happened to this file on *master*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out what happened. Someone else branched off of my feature branch to work on another feature, say *feature2*. After this new feature was finished the files added in *feature* were removed and it was merged with *master*. Thus the "deletion" was merged. When I tried to merge *master* into my branch I was also merging these deletions. Thus my files were being removed.

I figured this out in the following manner:

1. I checked out *feature* and did a merge with *master*.
2. Then I checked the log of `CMakeLists.txt` again using:

   `git log --all -- CMakeLists.txt`.
3. Next I noticed that the last commit with sha 1234 had a comment about removing `CMakeLists.txt`.
4. I checked the changes that happened in this commit using:

   `git diff 1234~1 1234 --summary`

   which showed me that `CMakeLists.txt` was being deleted.
5. I had a talk with the author of commit 1234 and figured out what was done.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You have to commit your changes before merging. You can merge only snapshots (commits), not files in staging area.

Comment: I have committed my changes, i.e. ```git add CMakeLists.txt``` and ```git commit -am "added CMakeLists.txt"```

Comment: I don't think git let's you merge uncommited changes anyways.

Comment: Certainly won't delete them in that case.